# Filter all the record having navigation property in Linq .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, navigation

I am developing a .net mvc web application.

I've got an error when filtering all the student records having enrollment records.

Actually I just want to get all the students who are enrolled in any courses.

I'm using the function count() as shown in the figure but it doesn't work and get errors.

[image]

Comment: can you show your code ? image is not help. Including your models.

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: Explain thrown error message including stack trace if any. The error should be related with your model data collection, it still unclear what kind of error occurred.

Comment: I am using this to filter  and get error
studentList.Where(s=>s.Enrollments.Count()>0);

Comment: Use a different variable to get count from `studentList`because you are using `studentList` in other statements too . try this one  `bool count = studentList.Where(s => s.Enrollments).Count() > 0;`

Comment: Use this quey: studentList = studentList.Where(s => s.Enrollments.Any());

Comment: thanks everyone !. I can't find the way using "where" to filter on the studentList I have. So I have to come back to my repository class and   define a function like this and use it in my controller:


         public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentHavingEnrollment()
        {
            var studentList = (from s in DbContext.Students
                         join e in DbContext.Enrollments on s.ID equals e.StudentID
                         select s).Distinct();
            return studentList;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `count`, try using `any`:

```
studentList.Where(s => s.Enrollments.Any())
```